# Sharing an object between files C#

Tags: c#, object, oop

I have to say that I'm a newbie in oop.
I have a .NET Framework app with a MainForm.cs class. I also created an object 'Book' in Book.cs class:

```
namespace SimpleAudiobookPlayer.Model
{
    class Book
    {
        public string Title
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public string Author
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public int Chapters
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public string Path
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public int LastReadChapter
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public TimeSpan EndTime
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public List<string> ChaptersPaths
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public Book(string title, string author, int chapters, string path, int lastReadChapter, TimeSpan endTime, List<string> chaptersPaths)
        {
            this.Title = title;
            this.Author = author;
            this.Chapters = chapters;
            this.Path = path;
            this.LastReadChapter = lastReadChapter;
            this.EndTime = endTime;
            this.ChaptersPaths = chaptersPaths;
        }
    }
}
```

In MainForm I create a Book and I work with this Book. After that I need to use this Book in Program.cs file. How can I do it? Previously I worked in C++ and I know about extern keyword (in c++). Is in C# something simmilar?

Comment: It is very unusual to put code in program.cs in a winforms application.  What are you actually trying to do

Comment: YOu also do not show how you are creating and storing instances of Book (the actual class is really not very interesting)

Comment: I need to run one line of code in Program.cs

Comment: You have not shown how you create and store book instances. I mean I can guess but you will say "Yes but I dont have a list of books, I have one instance called b1". Still *very* curious about putting app login in program.cs (>15 years writing winforms apps - never done it). That file is purely for booting up the app

Comment: FYI a .Net app doesn't work from *files*, but from *classes* that are compiled from source files. One file may contain multiple classes and a class definition may be spread over multiple files

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess

Firt change

```
class Book
{
```

to

```
public class Book
{
```

Becuase its needed outside the file it declared in

Now in Program.cs do

```
 var Book = new Book("title", "author", .....);
```

I know this is almost certainly not what you want, I bet you already have a book instance or 2 but you have not said where or how they are created or stored (I dont mean in a database, i just mean 'is it a list, an array, just a sigle variable...')

Comment: easier example: in mainform I have an Integer and I want to access it in Program.cs. How to fo it?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, why would you want to put code in `Program.cs` file? Every `Form` you add in your project is in itself a `Class` and you can perform all your `Book.cs` manipulations in any `Form` class.

Comment: Please don't post answers that should be comments. It will attract downvotes, which activity inhibits you from reaching the 50 rep required to comment

Comment: You usually share state not between 'files' but putting variables into memory. You can have shared state of course in file storage too. Now, program.cs is usually the main program flow. So your Forms are also classes in their own right, think of Program.cs as the 'orchestrator' and each class with their own fiddle or tuba or other instrument. If your app is a Windows Form application for example, often you have mot code in your Forms. I do not see the question you have anyways. Just because your project don't need any code into the Program.cs file dont mean other projects dont need it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).